# Finding the possibilities of Jordan Canonical Form When Given Characteristic Polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that the characteristic polynomial of $T:V \to V $ is $$P_T(t) = -(t-3)^3(t+1)^2t^4$$

(i) If $T$ has precisely 3 eigenvectors up to scaling, what are the possibilities for the Jordan Canonical Form of $T$ (Assume that these are writtent in the standard way with blocks ordered by decreasing eigenvalues and decreasing block size)

(ii) If $T$ has precisely 4 eigenvectors up to scaling, what are the possibilities for the Jordan Canonical Form of $T$. Give one example.

(iii) Suppose that the minimal polynomial of $T$ is $$M_T(t) = (t-3)(t+1)t^4 $$

what is the Jordan Canonical Form of $T$?

==============

My thoughts:

(i) Having three precise eigenvectors $\implies$ having three Jordan Blocks, each size of the blocks can't exceed its corresponding eigenvalue's multiplicity. So biggest block for eigenvalue 3 is 3x3 and biggest block for eigenvalue 2 is 2x2, and biggest for eigenvalue 1 is 4x4.
Am I right? It seems that there is only one possibility

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        3 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1  & 0 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 1 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 0 & 1\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 0 & 0\\
        \end{matrix}
$$

(iii) When given a minimal polynomial,

the only possibility is below

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1  & 0 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 1 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 0 & 1\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 0 & 0\\
        \end{matrix}
$$

so basically, we only have one 4x4 block corresponding to eigenvalue 0.
For the rest, because the characteristic polynomial is $P_T(t) = -(t-3)^3(t+1)^2t^4$ so that the in (iii) question, we can't have four 1x1 eigenvalue -1 or eigenvalue -3 blocks. The max number of blocks for eigenvalue -1 is two and the max number of blocks for eigenvalue 3 is three.

as long as there is at least one block associates with eigenvalue -1 and one block associates with eigenvalue 3

Also, each block (with either eigenvalue -1 or eigenvalue 3) is at most 1x1 size.

all size adds up to 5x5,( only eigenvalue -1 and eigenvalue 3)

Comment: (i) is correct—each block needs to be as large as possible, since there's only one eigenvector per eigenvalue. As for (iii): What are the minimal polynomials of various Jordan blocks? Which ones match the given information?

Comment: @GregMartin Could u check if my (i) matrix is correct ? So when the precise number of eigenvectors up to scaling is given, there is only one Jordan Canonical Form possibility ?

Comment: Not always, just when there's only one eigenvector per distinct eigenvalue. Your matrix isn't quite correct: notice there are six eigenvectors for it, including four with eigenvalue $0$.

Comment: @GregMartin should have 1 above the zero eigenvalue ?

Comment: @GregMartin I've reediting my thoughts on original post, could you check if my thoughts are correct?

Comment: (i) is correct. The possibility you write out for (iii) isn't correct: what is its characteristic polynomial?

Comment: @GregMartin could check if I'm right about the (iii) now, thanks so much